# The locate command cannot find obvious directory?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, locate

I have a directory called `OC` located in `/home/raph/OC`.

I've updated the database with the `updatedb` command and i still can't find the directory.

I've seen in an another post that the problem could come from the `/etc/updatedb.conf` file.

I checked it and everything is normal(meaning that `/home/raph/` is not in `#PRUNEPATHS`)

Does anyone have an idea why i can't find that obvious directory?

@ByteCommander i indeed forgot to mention it but when i use the `find` command i am able to find it :

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdcAY.png)

@muru When i check the /etc/updatedb.conf file here is what i get :

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXCVe.png)

Comment: Did you use correct capitalization? (i.e. did you run `locate OC` and not `locate oc` as your directory is in uppercase and file names are case sensitive) You can also check if something else is run instead of `locate` that has the same name or is aliased to that using `type -a locate`.

Comment: Also, is `find` able to find it? Run `find /home/raph -name OC -exec ls -ld {} \;` to search it and print some info about it.

Comment: There's also `PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS` and `PRUNEFS`. Does `/home/raph/OC` fall afoul of either?

Comment: Did you try running `updatedb` under `sudo` and then `locate` with `sudo` as well?  If it can find it this way, then perhaps there is a file permission problem?

Comment: @Ray Yes i have tried under sudo and it still doesn't work..

Comment: As a sanity check, I suggest commenting out PRUNEFS and then re-running `updatedb`.   You can also take a look at the `man` pages.  There are the `--verbose` and `--debug-pruning` options that you can try.